# MySQL index + math operators

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have RatingTable:

```
UserID int,
Rating int,
BanMask int,
index rating_index (Rating DESC),
index ban_index (BanMask ASC)
```

Let's say there're over 5 million rows in this table and only ~100 really banned users.

Will select query still be optimized if I use bit math operations on indexed field? 
Are this 2 queries will use index optimization?

```
SELECT * FROM ProfileTable 
WHERE BanMask > 0 
ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

vs

```
SELECT * FromProfileTable 
WHERE (BanMask & (1 << 2)) > 0 
ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

And second quistion. Should I add index on Rating + BanMask fields for better optimizations? Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX rating_ban_index ON ProfileTable (Rating DESC, BanMask ASC)
```

Comment: You have a potentially bigger reason for which MySQL may not choose to use any of your current indices: you are doing `SELECT *`.  Which columns do you actually need?

Comment: I really need *, this profile table contains entire profile description: id, name, games statistic. Does selected columns matter in this case? I can select only ID in the first pass and then select the reset of the data.

Comment: How many bits are used inside BanMask field? What is the largest value inside that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm for yourself which indexes are used for a given query by using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html).

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: RatingTable
         type: index
possible_keys: ban_index
          key: rating_index
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using where
```

You should study this manual page to get an explanation of the output: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html

I expect no index can be used for your query using the expression.

```
WHERE (BanMask & (1 << 2)) > 0
```

The EXPLAIN report shows:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: RatingTable
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

In general, an index cannot be used if your indexed column on the left side of the comparison operator is referenced in an expression or in a function. It must be a "bare" column.

Indexes work when you search for values that are together by sort order of the index. Your example searches for every 4th value in the BanMask, those that have the bit in the 4's place set. Those values are not consecutive, they're spread out. MySQL won't use the index to search all over the range of values like that, because ultimately that would be just as costly as scanning the whole table.

As for your second question, about adding an index on `(Rating DESC, BanMask ASC)`, the answer is it may help to avoid the filesort. But it won't help search the BanMask.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: RatingTable
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: Rating
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using where
```

Comment: Thanks! I used explain and my tests confirmed all you have written. Bit operations break using index. Adding index (Rating, BanMask) reduces execution time. Looks like having a separate column for every Ban reason instead of mask is most simple and reliable way if I want it to be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround for `BanMask > 0`, but not the other query *which is different*.

Instead of having the `BanMask` having a bunch of different non-zero values, have a single value that says banned.

One way is to have another column that is just true/false, and do

```
WHERE banned = 1  ORDER BY Rating DESC  LIMIT ..
INDEX(banned, Rating)  -- in _this_ order
```

A variant of that is to have a "generated" column (if you have a new enough version of MySQL/MariaDB) that computes true/false from `BanMask`.

The real benefit of the above is that the `LIMIT` can be seen and used.  That is, only 10 rows need be looked at.  All other solutions must scan lots of rows, possibly the whole table.

Here are some generic rules:

- The *first* column(s) of an index should be tested with `=`.
- Once you test a column with a range (`BanMask > 0`), the column can be used, but no further columns are useful.
- Hiding a column in a function (in your case `&` is a function), makes it not possible to use that column in the index.

For the original Question and no generated column, then I would expect `INDEX(Rating)` to be the only useful index.  Since you are asking for all columns (`SELECT *`), it is not practical to expand it to "covering".

Comment: Thanks! Idea of reducing the number of rows that possibly contain value I'm looking for is interesting